# Time cost severely different when copying the same data in Python

Tags: python, numpy

Time cost severely different when copying the same data in Python.

I have two `numpy` matrices, of the same size but stores in two different objects. Now I will copy the same data into these two objects slice by slice. However, the first copying cost about 0.3s but the second one only cost 0.01s. See the following code and comments:

```
import numpy as np, time

data1 = np.zeros([32, 1024, 1024, 3], np.uint8)
data2 = np.zeros([32, 1024, 1024, 3], np.uint8)

src = np.load('C:/ffhq/npy/000000.npy', 'r') # <== src is of size [40000, 1024, 1024, 3]

indices = np.random.permutation(src.shape[0]) # <== randomly permutate the indices

s = 0
for t in range(400):
    e = s + 32

    tic1 = time.time()
    for k in range(s, e):
        data1[k - s] = src[indices[k]]
    toc1 = time.time()

    tic2 = time.time()
    for k in range(s, e):
        data2[k - s] = src[indices[k]]
    toc2 = time.time()

    diff = data2 - data1

    s += 32
    print(toc1 - tic1) # <== Here, time cost is ~= 0.3s
    print(toc2 - tic2) # <== Here, time cost is ~= 0.01s
    print(np.min(diff), np.max(diff))

    print('')
```

The only difference between the two copying lies in the order in code. So why?

Answer (score 1):

The first copy loads everything into memory and perhaps into the CPU cache.  The second copy then incurs much less latency because it doesn't need to read from disk.

Note you are using `mmap_mode='r'` in `np.load()` which means the "load" does not actually load any data beyond the NumPy header.  If you want to load everything into memory at the start, just remove the `'r'` argument entirely, and you'll have a more fair comparison.